# Имитация нажатия клавиши

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
  var e = jQuery.Event("click");
  jQuery("a").trigger(e);
```

Почему не работает данный код?

У меня на странице только одна ссылка.

Пример [отсюда](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) взял.

И можно ли применить данную функцию для другого окна?

Comment: Добавляйте ссылки как ссылки >.<

Answer (score 4):

Глубже копайте. Думаю, что подробнее о методе **trigger()** вы не читали, посему рекомендую - [.trigger( eventType [, extraParameters] )](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

P.S. Набросал вам [простой примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/JR8VV/) Может понятней будет

Comment: А можно ли применить данную функцию для другого окна?
Не моего.