# Не срабатывают команды jquery из консоли на сайте

Tags: jquery

В общем есть такая страничка
https://www.igame.com/eye-test/?fbs=30

Типа проверка цветовосприятия. Нужный квадрат всегда имеет один и тот же класс
.thechosenone

Казалось бы, что может быть проще, чем писать каждый ход в консоли
`$('.thechosenone').click()` и собственно, проходить эту штуку.

Но оно почему то не работает.

Стало любопытно, что за магия.
Оказалось, что не работают даже селекторы, типа $('.thechosenone'), хотя jquery подключен. Как так можно заблокировать стандартное поведение ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Имитация нажатия клавиши](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/82048/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b8)

Comment: Всё проще: `.thechosenone` находится в `iframe`, поэтому через `$('.thechosenone')` до него не достучаться.

Comment: Вы упретесь в кросс-доменные запросы. Нужно по хитрому дергать класс.